# How to write data to different sheets using xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I have date attribute in the xlsx table. This is a report for a week long period.
I want to split it up by date. The result xlsx file should have 7 sheets and information relevant for each sheet should be placed there.

I use this class for writing:

```
class DictWriter:
    def __init__(self, workbook, worksheet, fieldnames):
        self.workbook = workbook
        self.worksheet = worksheet
        self.fieldnames = fieldnames
        self.nrow = 1

    def writerow(self, d):
        for k in d:
            ncol = self.fieldnames.index(k)
            self.worksheet.write(self.nrow, ncol, d[k])
        self.nrow += 1

    def writeheader(self):
        for ncol, fieldname in enumerate(self.fieldnames):
            self.worksheet.write(0, ncol, fieldname)
```

and in the beginning of the iteration (I iterate through HTTP JSON result section in file). The creation of worksheet is executed only once before the loop:

```
def file_generator():
    link = "http://example.com"
    client = requests.get(link)
    response = client.json()['response']
    if response['httpStatus'] == 200:
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('WeeklyReport.xlsx', {'strings_to_numbers': True})
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        data_table = response['data']['data']
        fieldnames = ["Date", "Advertiser", "Offer", "Revenue"]
        writer = DictWriter(workbook, worksheet, fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for d in data_table:
               row_dict = {"Date": d['Stat']['date'], "Advertiser": d['Advertiser']['company'], "Offer": d['Offer']['name'], "Revenue": d['Stat']['revenue']}
                writer.writerow(row_dict)
```

How should I modify the existing logic to write all records by date in sheets?

In my case, I did this way:

```
def key_value_gen(k):
    result = date.today() - timedelta(k)
    result = result.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    yield result
    yield 1

class DictWriter:
    def __init__(self, workbook, worksheet, fieldnames):
        self.workbook = workbook
        self.worksheet = worksheet
        self.fieldnames = fieldnames
        self.nrows = dict(map(key_value_gen, range(0, 8)))

    def writerow(self, d, condition=0):
        for k in d:
            ncol = self.fieldnames.index(k)
            self.worksheet.write(self.nrows[self.worksheet.name], ncol, d[k])
        print self.worksheet.name
        self.nrows[self.worksheet.name] += 1

    def changeworksheet(self, worksheet):
        self.worksheet = worksheet

    def writeheader(self):
        for ncol, fieldname in enumerate(self.fieldnames):
            self.worksheet.write(0, ncol, fieldname)
```

but it doesn't work properly (creates 7 sheets, but writes only in the first one) when I cast:

```
    for day in range(1,8):
        daydelta = date.today() - timedelta(day)
        daydelta = daydelta.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        sheet = workbook.add_worksheet(daydelta)
        sheets[sheet.name] =  worksheet
```

and then:

```
writer.changeworksheet(sheets[d['Stat']['date'].encode('utf-8')])
```

in the body of the loop.
How to modify it to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar type where I needed multiple worksheets for different data - I found it easiest to first make sure the data coming in was ordered by whatever I was deciding the worksheets by - in your case the date.  Then need to make the worksheets and put in how to know when to use a different one. I am at work so just pulled off what I had used or would have thought out what to use in your instance.  Hope this helps some.

```
worksheetNE = workbook.add_worksheet('Northeast Region')
worksheetNW = workbook.add_worksheet('Northwest Region')
worksheetSE = workbook.add_worksheet('Southeast Region')
if region.upper()=='NORTHEAST REGION':
    worksheet=worksheetNE
elif region.upper()=='NORTHWEST REGION':
    worksheet=worksheetNW
elif region.upper()=='SOUTHEAST REGION':
    worksheet=worksheetSE
```